# UDF that returns a table

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

In BigQuery, how does one write a UDF that returns a table?  What I would like is a CTE that is able to accept parameters.  As far as I can tell, UDFs only returns scalars, am I correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In BigQuery, you now have [`table functions`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/table-functions):

> A table function, also called a table-valued function (TVF), is a user-defined function that returns a table.

An example (found in the Google documentation):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE FUNCTION mydataset.names_by_year(y INT64)
AS
  SELECT year, name, SUM(number) AS total
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`
  WHERE year = y
  GROUP BY year, name
```

To execute it:

```
SELECT * FROM mydataset.names_by_year(1950)
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 7):

UDF can return ARRAYS of different types including ARRAY of STRUCTs

But obviously it is not the same as returning table, which is not really supported by BigQuery UDF [yet]

P.S. If you have specific issue that you want to resolve  - ask specific question and someone will help

Below are two relatively naive and useless (from practical standpoint) examples - but I hope they show concept of using ARRAYS to mimic at some extend CTE

> Example #1

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION pseudoCTE(x INT64, y INT64) AS (
  GENERATE_ARRAY(x, y)
);
SELECT * FROM UNNEST(pseudoCTE(1,5)) z
```

with result

```
Row z    
1   1    
2   2    
3   3    
4   4    
5   5
```

> Example #2

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION pseudoCTE(x INT64, y INT64) AS (
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT z AS id, RAND() AS value
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(x, y)) z)
);
SELECT * FROM UNNEST(pseudoCTE(1,5))   

Row id  value    
1   1   0.9319445195173228   
2   2   0.36404932965409453  
3   3   0.4615807541752828   
4   4   0.5504890432993448   
5   5   0.29635275888268836
```